# change terminal command to no return

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, command

I need to change the terminal command

```
stat file.txt | echo "File exists"
```

so that I don't get any output if the file doesn't exist and only the echo-part when it exists. what is the easiest way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  probably mean:

```
stat file > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "File exists"
```

Comment: looks good, but can you explain it, especially the dev/null/ part? :)

Comment: > /dev/null 2>&1 takes care, that no command output from stat will occur. the part after && gets executed, when the previous command returns "successful" as exit-code (i.e. 0)

Answer (score 2):

`echo` ignores it standard input, so it doesn't matter what, if anything, `stat` produces. Also, you don't need to run `stat` simply to check if a file exists.

```
[ -e file.txt ] && echo "File exists"
```

If the `[` command has a zero exit status (which happens when file.txt exists), then the `echo` is executed. Otherwise, the `echo` is not executed.

Comment: thanks, that is already great. but i need it linked with the stat command.

Comment: Why? You aren't anything specific to `stat`. Any output it produces is discarded by the subshell created on the right-hand side of the pipe.